# What is the proper way to extend the behavior of a custom Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written my own Angular directive called `<my-table>` since I use it multiple times, passing in different data to display. All of the tables have a button that when clicked, a popup form appears, like so:

[image: popup example]

However, for one of the `<my-table>` directives, I want to extend the behavior so that it acts slightly different from the other `<my-table>`s. For example, let's say that for the form that pops up, an alert box will appear when you click `Submit`, displaying data present in that `<my-table>`'s scope.

My question is, what is the best way extend the behavior of a given directive while still being able to access the directive's scope? Is this possible, or am I simply using directives incorrectly?

Comment: *"Is this possible, or am I simply using directives incorrectly?"* Depends on how you implemented directive in the first place.

Comment: You might get a lot more useful help on with this question if you post a plunkr/codepen with the directive (or an example directive).

Comment: I attempted to using something like the following: `<my-table add-additional-behavior></my-table>` where `add-additional-behavior` is another directive. However, it didn't seem like I was able to share data between the two directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something to this extent:

```
<my-table on-submit="doSomething(message)"></my-table>
```

In your my-table directive definition you would bind your callback to the scope:

```
scope: {
      'submit': '&onSubmit'
    },
```

Then in your controller you define your function:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(message) {
  alert(message);
}
```

In your template, where you define the submit button, you would do:

```
<button ng-click="submit({message: 'bye!'})"></button>
```

You can reference angular's documentation for more info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive